Slave women owned by multiple people and paternal certainty
https://sunnah.com/abudawud:2270
In the above hadith a woman was owned by multiple people and had a child whose parentage was questionable. Would this not be considered Zina for multiple owners to cohabit with a slave girl since it would cause paternal uncertainty? Or was this not zina since the prophet only laughed at the situation? please provide proofs thanks.

The Prophet ﵆ laughed at the solution used to settle the custody dispute, not as an approval of what the three men had done. This happened in Yemen which had recently surrendered to Islamic rule so it is likely that the act of the conception had occurred prior to Islamic rule.
